# Laravel dispatched job not returning system process list

Tags: laravel

I have a job that contains some code the calls the `Process Status` command.

```
$result = `ps -aux | grep horizon:work`;
```

When I run this on the server through ssh it returns a few result as expected. However, when the laravel queue worker dispatches this event it retuns null. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Im still unsure why I wasn't recieving the expected information however, I've change the script to use the `Process` class as followed and it's now working. If someone would like to explain why this wasn't working it would be appreciated.

```
$process_count = 0;

$process = new Process(['ps', 'aux']);
$process->run();
$command_output = $process->getOutput();


foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $command_output) as $line) {
    if (Str::contains($line, "horizon:work")) {
        $process_count ++;
    }
}

if($process_count <= 5){
    \Log::error("Queue is down");
    return;
}
```